# Can we handle the chrome alert which appears while automating the webpage using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please follow the below mentioned steps:

1.) go to this website :  http://demo.guru99.com/V4/index.php

2.)punch in any junk login id and password , and then the dialog box appears says:
USER OR PASSWORD IS NOT VALID

3.)Q1: Is there any way I can punch in the "ok" button in this dialog box ???because I can't inspect the element of this dialog box.

4.)Q2: When u try to login to gmail [ password shouldn't be saved], after punching the login details, it asks, do you want to save this password for this site ? Can this popup be handled ? because here also I can't inspect any information .

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** Selenium can interact with javascript (browser based) alerts using the Alert interface.

You can try any of the following:

using the explicit wait

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver).withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(500,msecs).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class  
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept();
```

directly getting the alert

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

using webdriver / chromedriver capabilities (to handle unexpected alert exception)

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
```

**Q2:** I'm unable to replicate the save password popup for gmail. However, you should be able to do it by using `.dismiss();` instead of `.accept();`.

**Note:** If you're using google chrome for testing, be reminded that chrome usually updates automatically. Selenium alert interaction may not work all of a sudden if it is not compatible with the latest chrome version. With this, I suggest you keep your chromedriver exe and java bindings updated.

Comment: Hey, how to pass these capabilities in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Is there any way I can punch in the "ok" button in this dialog box ???because I can't inspect the element of this dialog box.

Answer: For scenarios where you need to handle an alert, you can write a generic method similar to the one mentioned below, and pass the appropriate arguments while invoking/calling it:

```
public static void handleAlert(WebDriver driver, boolean accept) {
  Alert popup = driver.switchTo().alert();

  if (accept)
      popup.accept();
  else
      popup.dismiss();

}
```

While calling above method, you can pass **true**, when you want to accept the alert and **false** when you do not want to accept it.

Q2: When u try to login to gmail [ password shouldn't be saved], after punching the login details, it asks, do you want to save this password for this site ? Can this popup be handled ? because here also I can't inspect any information .

Answer: Solution in this scenario will depend on which browser is being used. As, you are using **Chrome** browser, you can use following to code to handle the required pop-up:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions --disable-extensions-file-access-check --disable-extensions-http-throttling --disable-infobars --enable-automation --start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("credentials_enable_service", false);
  options.setExperimentalOption("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries or above solutions do not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavascriptExecutor to accept alert:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept the alert box pop out as follows.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alertText = alert.getText();
System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
alert.accept();
File outputFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String imageDetails = "C:\\Images";
File screenShot = new File(imageDetails).getAbsoluteFile();
FileUtils.copyFile(outputFile, screenShot);
System.out.println("Screenshot saved: {}" + imageDetails);
driver.close();
```